# Console logging using script command output unreadable

Tags: shell-script, python, serial-port, typescript

I wanted to log my program's (the python program boots up a headless embedded device connected to a serial port) output to a text file `console_log.txt` using a shell script, for which, I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cd ~/Scripts;pwd;script -c \"python test.py $1\" ~/Output/console_log_$current_time.txt;exec $SHELL"
```

The above writes unreadable (non ASCII) characters to the file along the lines of:

```
捓楲瑰猠慴瑲摥漠⁮桔牵摳祡〠‶灁楲⁬〲㜱〠㨳㔲㈺‸䵐䤠呓ഊ上⹯漠⁦慰慲敭整獲瀠潲楶敤⁤祢琠敨甠敳⁲›ㄠ਍਍敔瑳漠瑰潩⁮湥整敲⁤›〠਍獕湩⁧敤慦汵⁴潣普杩牵瑡潩⁮楦敬⸮⸮਍਍⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪桔⁥潣普杩牵瑡潩⁮楦敬琠慨❴⁳潧湩⁧潴戠⁥獵摥椠⁳›㰠潮敮ാ猊慴瑲湩⁧慭湩猠牣灩൴⼊潨敭愯瑵浯瑡潩㑮愯瑵浯瑡潩⽮噄㥆弹畁潴慭楴湯਍栯浯⽥畡潴慭楴湯⼴畡潴慭楴湯䐯䙖㤹䅟瑵浯瑡潩⽮湉異⽴਍❛灳捥牴浵睟形档物⹰慷❶‬洧污彥欸眮癡Ⱗ✠灳捥牴浵湟形楤捳㍟〶⸰慷❶‬猧数瑣畲彭扮损楨灲眮癡Ⱗ✠灳捥牴浵睟形楤捳㕟〸⸰慷❶‬琧獥⹴慷❶‬洧污彥㘱⹫慷❶‬昧汭扟灵慟瑴潟杲眮癡崧㠠਍栯浯⽥畡潴慭楴湯⼴畡潴慭楴湯䐯䙖㤹䅟瑵浯瑡潩⽮湉異⽴潣普杩琮瑸਍††††††††††唠䕓⁒†††倠䑉䄠䍃卅⁓佃䵍乁ൄ⼊敤⽶瑴啹䉓㨸††††畡潴慭楴湯‴㈠㘲㔷䘠⸮⸮氠杯湩楟楮൴⼊敤⽶瑴啹䉓㨹††††畡潴慭楴湯‴㈠㘲㔶䘠⸮⸮氠杯湩楟楮൴匊牥慩⁬潐瑲⁳楬瑳㨠†❛✹‬㠧崧਍敓楲污瀠牯獴㨠†❛搯癥琯祴单㥂Ⱗ✠搯癥琯祴单㡂崧਍桃灩敳⁴‱›ㄠ㄰਍桃灩敳⁴′›ㄠ㄰਍潂牡⁤‱敓楲污倠牯⁴›⼠敤⽶瑴啹䉓ഹ䈊慯摲㈠匠牥慩⁬潐瑲㨠†搯癥琯祴单㡂਍潂牡ㅤ䤠⁐›ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㈳਍潂牡㉤䤠⁐›ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㘳਍潂牡㍤䤠⁐›ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㔲਍潂牡㑤䤠⁐›ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㜲਍潂牡㕤䤠⁐›ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㠵਍汯⁤敲畳瑬搠汥猠捵散獳⹳⸮‮慰獳਍潔‽❛牳敥慫瑮⹨䁳獤杰挮浯崧਍灓楬⁴潶灩‽ര⨊⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪਍⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪潓湵⁤慃摲䌠湯捥楴湯⩳⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪പ⨊⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪਍佂剁ㅄⴠ㸭戠弱畯彴潰瑲漽瑵档ⰱ戠弱湩灟牯㵴湩档റ䈊䅏䑒′ⴭ‾㉢潟瑵灟牯㵴畯捴㉨‬㉢楟彮潰瑲椽据㉨਍⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪പഊ嬊⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✹‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✸‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✳‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✲‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✱‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✰‬⼧敤⽶瑴卹✰൝嬊⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✹‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✸‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✳‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✲‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✱‬⼧敤⽶瑴啹䉓✰‬⼧敤⽶瑴卹✰൝䈊慯摲†椠⁰†‽㜱⸲㠲㐮㈮㤰਍慇整慷⁹灩†㴠ㄠ㈷㈮⸸⸴㔲ഴ䌊浯瀠牯
```

Or `gedit` displays messages like:

```
Could not open the file “/home/user4/con…g_2017.04.06-16.05.48.txt”.
Unexpected error: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input
```

when I try to open the file.

When I run some thing simpler like:

```
script -c ifconfig ~/user4/Scripts/test.txt
```

it runs just fine, i.e, I get the expected output at the log file. How to avoid such unreadable characters?

Comment: what is the output of `python -c "import sys;print(sys.getdefaultencoding())"'` and of `export | grep LANG` ? Make sure both is set to `UTF-8`

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but why are you using gnome-terminal? Why not just `bash -c . . . `?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you just direct the output of the python program to a file, or only with `script`? i.e. with `python test.py > outfile` instead of `script -c "..." outfile` ?

Comment: @MichaelD., the output of `python -c "import sys;print(sys.getdefaultencoding())"` is `ascii` and that of `export | grep LANG` is `declare -x GDM_LANG="en_US"
declare -x LANG="en_IN"
declare -x LANGUAGE="en_IN:en"`

Comment: @terdon, I'm using gnome-terminal because I need to view the execution asa well. The `script` command helps me view the entire log for that particular run of the script if the log exceeds the terminal buffer limit.

Comment: @ilkkachu, even with direction using `>` I get the same! :(

Comment: Setting all your locales to `en_IN.UTF-8`. Your python file should be encoded to `utf-8`. add this line to the top of your python file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` That should generate an `utf-8` encoded textfile which will open.

Comment: @MichaelD., this kinda fixed it because when I open the text file, it still is not readable and displays `The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again.` But there is a `Retry` button on top of `gedit` with `Character encoding` selected as `Current Locale(UTF-8)`. When I click `Retry`, I get the logs! Can this get better? :)

Comment: @skrowten_hermit, I thought so, I don't think there's any reason for `script` to mangle the output, so it's probably not an issue with that. You might want to try to find out what part of the python program produces the output with broken encoding (and if it is actually broken)

Answer (score 3):

In case if you are running python script in Linux environment, follow the below steps before running the script:

```
$ script console_log.txt
$ run your python script
$ exit  (After the script completes execution)
```

Entire console logs will be captured in "console_log.txt"