# python script output won't be directed to file

Tags: logs, python, stdout, output

I have a python script. It has a `SimpleLogger` with `sys.stdout` as `output_stream`.

```
logger = SimpleLogger(level=LogLevel.DEBUG)
```

When I run it in console, I get the logs properly, but whenever I redirect the output to a file, nothing is found in the target.

I tried multiple ways:

1. python server.py > /tmp/x.log 2>&1
2. python server.py > /tmp/x.log

In both cases, the `/tmp/x.log` is empty.

I also tried `nohup python server.py`, but nothing has been written in `nohup.out`.

Comment: Refer this post [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463577/298480)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably just due to buffering. You will only see something in the file when enough output has been accumulated.  You can try using `python -u` to ask for unbuffered output, or set environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=` to any non-empty string, as documented in the Python [command line](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) documentation, or add a `.flush()` call after each `.debug()` or similar call.

Comment: Both solutions worked. Additionally, mentioning `buffer` remind me of `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable. I tried to set it to `1`; this solution worked as well. Would you please add this one to your answer? I think the credit is yours, plus it's better to sum the answer up in one place.